# What does parantheses mean in this case?

Tags: javascript, parentheses

What do parentheses mean in the following code? Do these parentheses have a certain meaning?

```
function disableSubmit () {
  ...
}
```

And also what do the parentheses mean if there is an `e` in between? For example,

```
function (e){
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is a function definition syntax and `e` is the argument of the `function`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: This is pretty basic JavaScript syntax. You may want to look for a good comprehensive introduction to the language.

Comment: Lots of downvotes on this question, implying a bad question.  But, I'm forced to wonder if the question is totally fine, just extremely basic?

Comment: Yes im a beginner therefor the question it very basic

Comment: There are literally more than 15,000,000 questions on Stack Overflow. Perhaps it was asked before (duplicate)?

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses represent arguments to the function. Empty parentheses means there are no arguments.

Also, in your second function, you have written it incorrectly (unless you are embedding the function as a parameter to another.) You need to name it like you did the first, like so

```
function someFunction(e){}
```

Comment: Ah yes missed that. Thanks